# Incorrect og:url in Open Graph while og:url in metatags is correct

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

When I scrape my website if I choose to see the detailed metatags the og:url contains the correct value:

```
<meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:url" content="https://safarisharing.com/trip/33" />
```

But, the debugger reports that; 
Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties:

```
og:url  https://safarisharing.com/public/images/favicon/android-icon-32x32.png
```

Where the favicon that it reports is just a rel: icon in link tags and makes no sense to be there... Also, the canonical url is set correctly.

This error triggers some warnings:

> **Could Not Follow Redirect Path**
>
> Using data from https://safarisharing.com/public/images/favicon/android-icon-32x32.png because there was an error following the redirect path.
>
> **Circular Redirect Path**
>
> Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
>
> **Could Not Follow Redirect**
>
> URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.
>
> **Mismatch og:url and canonical url**
>
> og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html.

I have no clue what the problem is and everything seems to be okay. Any idea?

Edit:

Guys I am having a next level mindf*ck right now. If I go to my site and type a random url lets say `https://safarisharing.com/ssdfdsfsdf/hgfjhfgjklfg/sdfjdsjsd/vxckvjxcklvj/dfkgjdfgkljdfk`
and then hit Scrape Again the Canonical URL changes to that [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9dmF.jpg). What the..

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will scrape the content of the HTML as it leaves your server, *before* any Javascript (or React) templates are rendered. If you `view-source` on those pages, you'll see the `<meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:url" content="https://safarisharing.com/favicon.ico"/>` line that FB is picking up. You'll need to alter that line on the server, rather than later via Javascript.

Comment: The tags are updated server-side. So the correct og:url is already set when it leaves the server. If you do cURL you will see that the first tag the server returns is the correct one.

Comment: I have same issue, have you found answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979453/why-ogurl-is-not-taken-from-meta-tags