# Why og:url is not taken from meta tags?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, share-open-graph

On my sharing page: https://tikex-dev.com/kubl/38fn/j1vd/2mi1

in header I specify a different `og:url` than the url itself, this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7ou5">
```

`og:url` should be point to an AWS S3 gif file.

Though when checking with Facebook debugger, it shows for `og:url` the 'normal', the sharing page, not the one set by meta tag. Why?

Using Next.js, page is rendered on server side.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find the solution?